# Mac -bash: node: command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, terminal

I am having problems running node.js from the terminal.

I have run the node.js installer for mac, but when I try to use the node command in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
-bash: node: command not found
```

I have been trying to look for a solution but all the suggestions I found, dont help

In the folder /usr/local/bin I have node and npm, but even when I navigate to the folder and run node, I still get the same error. I don't understand why this is happening, because I can see that node exists in the folder.

I also tried to edit the .bash_profile by adding /usr/local/bin but that didn't resolve the issue either

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Comment: Sounds like you don't have `/usr/local/bin` on your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I found the cause of the problem and posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

I had edited the .bash_profile to add the path to JAVA but I did not end it with a colon (:) so it ended up combining the path to JAVA with /usr/local/bin

Once I added the colon, everything started working

Answer (score 32):

```
brew search node
```

then `brew install node@version`, example:

```
brew install node@8

brew link node@8
node --version
```

Still getting node not found, try this:

```
brew link --overwrite --force node@8
```

Answer (score 7):

Try installing node with [homebrew](http://brew.sh) - `brew install npm` should do it

Answer (score 2):

If you have already installed node and still doesn't work, you might try running `brew link node`. You could create a force link if an error occurs while creating the link. `brew link --overwrite node`

Answer (score -1):

Simply run this command in your terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```